# What is the effective irreducible 3 body gravitational potential in the weak field limit?

Tags: general-relativity

In weak fields we know that the gravitational interaction between two point masses is determined by the potential:

$$V(r) = -\frac{m_1 m_2 G}{r}$$

where the $m_j$ are the masses of the objects, $r$ is the relative distance and $G$ is the gravitational constant. We can then use this to compute the interactions between multiple point masses by adding up mutual potentials between all pairs of the masses. However, this then ignores any irreducible many body interactions that arises from the fundamental non-linear nature of General Relativity (but also in quantum field theory the interaction between multiple particles cannot be fully accounted for by considering only the interaction between pairs of particles).  If we restrict our attention to 3 bodies, the effective potential energy function in the weak field limit should be of the form:

$$V(\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_2,\vec{r}_3)= -\sum_{i=1}^2\sum_{j=i+1}^3\frac{m_i m_j G}{|\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j|}+ V_{\text{irr}}(\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_2,\vec{r}_3)$$

The question is then what the explicit form of $V_{\text{irr}}(\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_2,\vec{r}_3)$ is.

Comment: No answer but some random thoughts.  How could we measure $V_{irr}$?  We could study simple 3-body systems (earth-moon-sun,  etc.) and see how their motion varies from numerical simulations that only use pair-wise forces.  We have interpreted these variations as being due to tidal forces, but what if some of the effects are due to non-zero $V_{irr}$?  We would need to study 3-body systems that are less subject to tidal forces (any candidates?) to disentangle the effects.  Could a non-zero $V_{irr}$ provide an explanation (or partial explanation) for dark matter?